# Parallelism employing TBB - What should be in our check list?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

Only very recently did the prospects of parallel programming caught my attention.
Since then I have used a variety of parallel programming libraries. Perhaps my
first stop was the Intel Thread Building Blocks(TBB). But, what often became the bottle-necks were the errors due to factors like Round-Offs and the unpredictable behaviour of these programmes in different processor architectures. Below is a piece of code which calculates the Pearsons Correlation Coefficient of two sets of values. It employs the very basic parallel patterns of the TBB - the *parallel_for* and *parallel_reduce* :

```
    // A programme to calculate Pearsons Correlation coefficient 

#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tbb/task_scheduler_init.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_reduce.h>
#include <tbb/blocked_range.h>
#include <tbb/tick_count.h>




using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;
const size_t n=100000;
double global=0;

namespace s //Namesapce for serial part
{
double *a,*b;
int j;
double mean_a,mean_b,sd_a=0,sd_b=0,pcc=0;
double sum_a,sum_b,i;
}

namespace p //Namespace for parallel part
{
double *a,*b;
double mean_a,mean_b,pcc;
double sum_a,sum_b,i;
double sd_a,sd_b;
}


class serials
{
public:
               void computemean_serial()
               {
                using namespace s;
            sum_a=0,sum_b=0,i=0;
                a=(double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                b=(double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                for(j=0;j<n;j++,i++)
                { 
                    a[j]=sin(i);
                    b[j]=cos(i);

                    sum_a=sum_a+a[j];
                    sum_b=sum_b+b[j];
                }
                mean_a=sum_a/n;
            mean_b=sum_b/n;
                cout<<"\nMean of a :"<<mean_a;
                cout<<"\nMean of b :"<<mean_b;
               }
               void computesd_serial()
               {
               using namespace s;
               for(j=0;j<n;j++)
               {sd_a=sd_a+pow((a[j]-mean_a),2);
                sd_b=sd_b+pow((b[j]-mean_b),2);
               }
                sd_a=sd_a/n;
               sd_a=sqrt(sd_a);
               sd_b=sd_b/n;
               sd_b=sqrt(sd_b);
               cout<<"\nStandard deviation of a :"<<sd_a;
               cout<<"\nStandard deviation of b :"<<sd_b;
               }
               void pearson_correlation_coefficient_serial()
               {
                using namespace s;
                pcc=0;
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                pcc+=(a[j]-mean_a)*(b[j]-mean_b);
                }
                pcc=pcc/(n*sd_a*sd_b);
                cout<<"\nPearson Correlation Coefficient: "<<pcc;
               }

};


class parallel
{
public:

class compute_mean 
{

double *store1,*store2;
public: 

double mean_a,mean_b;

    void operator()( const blocked_range<size_t>& r)
    {
    double *a= store1;
    double *b= store2;

    for(size_t i =r.begin();i!=r.end(); ++i)
    {    
         mean_a+=a[i];
         mean_b+=b[i];
    }
    }
    compute_mean( compute_mean& x, split) : store1(x.store1),store2(x.store2),mean_a(0),mean_b(0){}

    void join(const compute_mean& y) {mean_a+=y.mean_a;mean_b+=y.mean_b;}
    compute_mean(double* a,double* b): store1(a),store2(b),mean_a(0),mean_b(0){}
};

               class read_array
                {
               double *const a,*const b;

                 public:

             read_array(double* vec1, double* vec2) : a(vec1),b(vec2){}  // constructor copies the arguments into local store 
             void operator() (const blocked_range<size_t> &r) const {              // opration to be used in parallel_for 

                     for(size_t k = r.begin(); k!=r.end(); k++,global++)
                     {   
                         a[k]=sin(global);
                         b[k]=cos(global);
                     }

                 }};

            void computemean_parallel()
                        {
                        using namespace p;
                        i=0;
                        a=(double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                        b=(double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));

                parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t>(0,n,5000),read_array(a,b));
                compute_mean sf(a,b);
                parallel_reduce(blocked_range<size_t>(0,n,5000),sf);
                mean_a=sf.mean_a/n;
                mean_b=sf.mean_b/n;
                cout<<"\nMean of a :"<<mean_a;
                cout<<"\nMean of b :"<<mean_b;
               }

class compute_sd 
{
double *store1,*store2;
double store3,store4;
public: 
double sd_a,sd_b,dif_a,dif_b,temp_pcc;
void operator()( const blocked_range<size_t>& r)
{
    double *a= store1;
    double *b= store2;
    double mean_a=store3;
    double mean_b=store4;
    for(size_t i =r.begin();i!=r.end(); ++i)
    { 
     dif_a=a[i]-mean_a;
     dif_b=b[i]-mean_b;
     temp_pcc+=dif_a*dif_b;
     sd_a+=pow(dif_a,2);
     sd_b+=pow(dif_b,2);
    }}
    compute_sd( compute_sd& x, split) : store1(x.store1),store2(x.store2),store3(p::mean_a),store4(p::mean_b),sd_a(0),sd_b(0),temp_pcc(0){}
    void join(const compute_sd& y) {sd_a+=y.sd_a;sd_b+=y.sd_b;}
    compute_sd(double* a,double* b,double mean_a,double mean_b): store1(a),store2(b),store3(mean_a),store4(mean_b),sd_a(0),sd_b(0),temp_pcc(0){}
};


               void computesd_and_pearson_correlation_coefficient_parallel()
               {
               using namespace p;
               compute_sd obj2(a,b,mean_a,mean_b);
               parallel_reduce(blocked_range<size_t>(0,n,5000),obj2);
               sd_a=obj2.sd_a;
               sd_b=obj2.sd_b;
               sd_a=sd_a/n;
               sd_a=sqrt(sd_a);
               sd_b=sd_b/n;
               sd_b=sqrt(sd_b);
               cout<<"\nStandard deviation of a :"<<sd_a;
               cout<<"\nStandard deviation of b :"<<sd_b;
               pcc=obj2.temp_pcc;
               pcc=pcc/(n*sd_a*sd_b);
               cout<<"\nPearson Correlation Coefficient: "<<pcc;
               }
};

main()
{       
        serials obj_s;
        parallel obj_p;
        cout<<"\nSerial Part";
        cout<<"\n-----------";
        tick_count start_s=tick_count::now();
        obj_s.computemean_serial();
        obj_s.computesd_serial();
        obj_s.pearson_correlation_coefficient_serial();
        tick_count end_s=tick_count::now();
        cout<<"\n";
        task_scheduler_init init;
        cout<<"\nParallel Part";
        cout<<"\n-------------";
        tick_count start_p=tick_count::now();
        obj_p.computemean_parallel();
        obj_p.computesd_and_pearson_correlation_coefficient_parallel();
        tick_count end_p=tick_count::now();
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"\nTime Estimates";
        cout<<"\n--------------";
        cout<<"\nSerial Time :"<<(end_s-start_s).seconds()<<" Seconds";
        cout<<"\nParallel time :"<<(end_p-start_p).seconds()<<" Seconds\n";

}
```

Well ! it worked fine on a Windows Machine with a Core i5 inside it. It gave me absolutely the same values for every parameters in the output with parallel code manifold faster than the serial code. Here is my **output**:

**OS** : Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit **Processor** : core i5

```
Serial Part
-----------
Mean of a :1.81203e-05
Mean of b :1.0324e-05
Standard deviation of a :0.707107
Standard deviation of b :0.707107
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: 3.65091e-07

Parallel Part
-------------
Mean of a :1.81203e-05
Mean of b :1.0324e-05
Standard deviation of a :0.707107
Standard deviation of b :0.707107
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: 3.65091e-07

Time Estimates
--------------
Serial Time : 0.0204829 Seconds
Parallel Time : 0.00939971 Seconds
```

So what about the other machines ? If I say it will work fine then at least of some of my friends will say "Wait mate!  something is fishy." There were minor differences in the answers(between those produced by the parallel and serial code) in different machines though the parallel code was always faster than the serial one. So what made these differences? The conclusions,we came across, for this abnormal behaviour were the round-off errors which comes at the cost of excessive parallelism and the difference in processor architectures.

This leads to my questions :

- What are the precautions we need to take when we employ the parallel
  processing libraries in our codes to take advantage of multi-core
  processors?
- What are situations were we should not use the parallel approach even
  though there is availability of multiple processors?
- What is the best thing we can do to avoid the round-off errors?(Let me
  specify that I am not talking about enforcing mutexes and barriers which
  may sometime put a cap on the extend of parallelism but about 
  the simple programming tips which can be handy at times)

I'm very happy to see your suggestions regarding these questions. Please be free to answer
the part which best suits you if you have time limitations.

**Edit - I have included more results here**

**OS** : Linux Ubuntu 64 bit **Processor** : core i5

```
    Serial Part
    -----------
    Mean of a :1.81203e-05
    Mean of b :1.0324e-05
    Standard deviation of a :0.707107
    Standard deviation of b :0.707107
    Pearson Correlation Coefficient: 3.65091e-07

    Parallel Part
    -------------
    Mean of a :-0.000233041
    Mean of b :0.00414375
    Standard deviation of a :2.58428
    Standard deviation of b :54.6333
    Pearson Correlation Coefficient: -0.000538456

    Time Estimates
    --------------
    Serial Time :0.0161237 Seconds
    Parallel Time :0.0103125 Seconds
```

**OS** : Linux Fedora 64 bit **Processor** : core i3

```
Serial Part
-----------
Mean of a :1.81203e-05
Mean of b :1.0324e-05
Standard deviation of a :0.707107
Standard deviation of b :0.707107
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: 3.65091e-07

Parallel Part
-------------
Mean of a :-0.00197118
Mean of b :0.00124329
Standard deviation of a :0.707783
Standard deviation of b :0.703951
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: -0.129055

Time Estimates
--------------
Serial Time :0.02257 Seconds
Parallel Time :0.0107966 Seconds
```

**Edit**: After the change which timday has suggested

**OS** :Linux Ubuntu 64 bit **Processor** : corei5

```
Serial Part
-----------
Mean of a :1.81203e-05
Mean of b :1.0324e-05
Standard deviation of a :0.707107
Standard deviation of b :0.707107
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: 3.65091e-07

Parallel Part
-------------
Mean of a :-0.000304446
Mean of b :0.00172593
Standard deviation of a :0.708465
Standard deviation of b :0.7039
Pearson Correlation Coefficient: -0.140716

Time Estimates
--------------
Serial Time :0.0235391 Seconds
Parallel time :0.00810775 Seconds
```

Best Regards.

*Note1 : I'm not guaranteeing that the above piece of code is correct.I believe so.*

*Note2 : This piece of code was tested on Linux boxes as well.*

*Note3 : Different grain size combinations and auto-partition options were tried.*

Comment: Can you post the results from one or more of these "other architectures" please ?  I'm unclear whether you're saying you *only* get differences in the parallel code results, or *more* differences in the parallel code results, and what the magnitude of those differences is.

Comment: @timday: Thank You for the time. I have added more results.
You can see every results in LINUX boxes show anomalies but note that there were some LINUX boxes which had shown accurate results which I can't reproduce at this time. I am getting anomalies only in the parallel part. The magnitude of these differences are sometimes small but sometimes they are big.

Comment: @sjsam well it is not obvious what is wrong but according your result, there are probably some parts which are not cross platform compatible, the standard deviation from ubuntu seems to be giving totally wrong results, i suggests you take the "base" functions like sqrt and all the others and compare them, also size_t could have an impact. If you are using the same compilers will also matter. In addition check the sizeof(double) on each Platform, if it varies than this will greatly impact the result.

Comment: @OliverStutz: Thank You for the time.The behaviour of the basic functions like sqrt is indeed something to be looked at. Also majority of our platforms had an Intel 64 Architecture(Extended Instruction Set) where the **sizeof** double is 8 Byte.

Comment: Have you tried using the same read_array/compute_mean decomposition for both serial and parallel versions? Either change the serial version to initialise the array separate to computing the means, or else change the parallel version to initialise the array in the same loop that calculates the mean. I am wondering if some compilers are summing with a high precision result from sin() rather than a lower precision value from a[k].

Comment: @Brangdon: I haven't tried the same decomposition for both serial and parallel parts. Moreover, since a[k] is of the type double which is the return type of the sin(), how is the precision going to be an issue here??

Comment: The serial code is producing the same results on all platforms, and the parallel code isn't: this is a pretty big red flag there is some timing/race condition issue in the parallel code, and indeed the code simply seems to be making incorrect usage of TBB which is vulnerable to being exposed by timing differences making a difference to TBB's "splitting" behaviour (see my answer below).  IMHO OpenMP would be a much better tool for producing a parallel version of the serial code presented (TBB is useful for cases OpenMP can't handle), but this does appear to be a learning excercise for the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am deeply suspicious of the commented out `/*,mean_a(0),mean_b(0)*/` in the `compute_mean( compute_mean& x, split)` constructor.  Seems likely your differences could arise from uninitialized data polluting the results.  I'm guessing on the machines where you get consistent results, no task splitting is occurring or those members just happen to be on zeroed memory.

Similarly your `compute_sd( compute_sd& x, split)` leaves `store3` and `store4` uninitialized.

Comment: I am inclined to your first suggestion. Each time we operate on chunks of data mean_a and mean_b must be made zero.I have taken off the commendation from that line(Please see the edit).

But the values in `store3` and `store4` which are actually constants inside that routine are reassigned to `mean_a` and `mean_b`
in the course of the programme. Is their any need to re-initialise it after  the splitting constructor `compute_sd( compute_sd& x, split)`?
Also, the parallel code answers are more closer to that of the serial code after the edit you suggested..

Comment: Er, to me it looks clear: class compute_sd has members store3 and store4.  If a compute_sd instance is created using the "split" form of the constructor, then the instance created has store3 and store4 uninitialized and the first call to operator() will be using undefined values.  From the latter part of your comments above, I believe you have an incorrect understanding of C++ constructors and the TBB "split" mechanism.

Comment: You're right ! I should have realized earlier that the splitting constructor invoke another instance of compute_sd and it creates another stack of variables. This made me change that line as follows : `compute_sd( compute_sd& x, split) : store1(x.store1),store2(x.store2),store3(p::mean_a),store4(p::mean_b),sd_a(0),sd‌​_b(0),temp_pcc(0){}`

Answer (score 1):

> This leads to my questions :
>
> What are the precautions we need to take when we employ the parallel processing libraries in our codes to take advantage of multi-core processors?

Aside from the points in timday's answer, your problems do not seem to be specific to parallelism. Stable algorithms for computing with floating-point numbers are difficult to design; the lower determinism that is inherent in the efficient use of parallelism exposes problems that inadequate algorithms always had. See below for what I mean. You should test the robustness of the serial code with respect to the order of the input data before deciding whether the parallelism or the algorithm are responsible for numerical instability.

> What are situations were we should not use the parallel approach even though there is availability of multiple processors?

When there are insufficient operations in the loop to pay for the overhead. This depends on the algorithm, hardware and problem size.

> What is the best thing we can do to avoid the round-off errors?(Let me specify that I am not talking about enforcing mutexes and barriers which may sometime put a cap on the extend of parallelism but about the simple programming tips which can be handy at times)

Whether writing serial or parallel code, you should use algorithms that are designed for numerical stability. Those you were taught in high school were designed for ease of understanding! :-) For example, see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance.

Comment: It's been a while since I have put this post and almost forgot about it. I had some misunderstandings regarding the TBB Split Mechanisms. I'm about to have a revision of the TBB and Parallel algorithms. Your suggestions came exactly on time. Thank You.